# Ping succeeds but also fails (Android and Windows 7)

Tags: windows, networking, android

Ping says `Destination host unreachable`, but `Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0%`:

[image]

I have turned off the Windows firewall and the Kaspersky firewall.
How can I solve this?

On my Android phone the IP address is 192.168.1.33.

`ipconfig` output:

[image: ipconfig details]

[image: Dlink]

Comment: Please copy the text into your question ***as text***.

Comment: Did you disable the firewall service or turn off the firewall?

Comment: @spacenomyous I turned it off.

Comment: Did you see this question  https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8854/phone-doesnt-respond-to-ping

Comment: @spacenomyous Yes I have! I changed the settings.But it did solve the problem.

Comment: Can you ping other things? What about a trace route?

Comment: @spacenomyous Sorry.It was a mistake,I meant to say ""It did not solve the problem""

Comment: @spacenomyous  Trace route did not work .It says destination host unreachable.

Comment: why on earth do you use a camera to capture screenshot? use printscreen key or snipping tool. And those would be much simpler to right click > mark mode and copy the text then paste here

Answer (score 0):

Your pings are not suceeding but you are getting responses from your gateway.

You are pinging `.33` but getting valid `Destination not reachable` responses from `.111` (your own machine).

Receiving 4 replies is not a "success", it just means you got 4 replies. Your machine is telling you that the address is wrong or that the requested address is unroutable or unreachable.

Comment: @ Mokubai But the Ip address of my android device is 192.168.1.33.What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Turn off the firewall on your Android device. You may need root. The real question is why you need this.

Comment: I use MIT appinventer and tried connecting to it via The MIT Companion app on google play through WIFI.It did not connect my device.Are there any other ways to solve this other than root ?

Comment: Could be that your router doesn't support allowing communications between wireless devices, or between wired and wireless devices... replacing it might help...

Comment: It is a Wi-Fi Router.Wifi seems to be working fine on the android device.I can access Internet on the android through wifi.

Comment: But can you access other devices such as computers and other phones via Wifi? Older routers literally isolated devices so that all they could do was access the internet.

Comment: Unfortunately I dont have any other devices to which I can ping.But I've added the image from Dlink  page (edited my question(click on d link to see the image))(under advanced network)(Under WAN Ping,all the checkboxes are enabled).

Comment: WAN ping is Wide Area Network, as in your internet connection. For security you do not want that enabled. You should be looking for WIFI, not WAN.